# spring type conversion not working - Giving Type Mismatch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, kotlin

I have tried creating a custom converter as specified in - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-type-conversions#creating-a-custom-converter but I am still getting type mismatch when I am carrying out the conversion.

I am creating a converter class (PageToApiResponse) which converts from Page<*> to ResponseList. This converter is then added to registry in the WebConfig class. However when I want to implicitly convert from a Page< ProductDemand > to ResponseList in the controller I get a type mismatch (The service returns Page< ProductDemand >). I have tried annotating the converter class with @Component but that doesn't work.

The error is as follows: 
Required: ResponseList.
Found: Page< ProductDemand >

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the classes involved -

```
data class ResponseList(
    val total: Int,
    val limit: Int,
    val offset: Int,
    val results: List<*>
)
```

```
class PageToApiResponse : Converter<Page<*>, ResponseList> {

    override fun convert(source: Page<*>) = ResponseList(source.numberOfElements, source.size, source.number, source.content)
}
```

```
@Configuration
class WebConfig : WebMvcConfigurer {

    override fun addFormatters(registry: FormatterRegistry) {
        registry.addConverter(PageToApiResponse())
    }
}
```

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "Find demand by GPI")
    @ApiResponses(
        ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Demand results", response = ProductDemand::class, responseContainer = "List"),
        ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad input parameter"),
        ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
        ApiResponse(code = 429, message = "Too Many Requests")
    )
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('${Authorities.EXT_USAGE_VIEW}')")
    @GetMapping("")
    fun getDemand(
        @RequestParam(required = true) gpi: String,
        @PageableDefault(
            page = 0,
            size = 50,
            sort = ["molecule"],
            direction = Sort.Direction.DESC
        ) pageable: Pageable
    ): ResponseList = service.getDemand(gpi, pageable)
```

Comment: That isn't how the converter works. You need to call conversion service to do the conversion, it won't implicitly call the converter for you.

Comment: @M.Deinum I disagree - from their documentation -
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-type-conversions#1-implicit-conversion
"Beyond these explicit conversion using the ConversionService, Spring is also capable of implicitly converting values right in Controller methods for all registered converters:"

Comment: You can disagree but that isn't going to make the converters work like you want. The only implicit conversion that is done is for incoming requests to convert request parameters to method arguments NOT for outgoing data. It will not automagically convert the return type to `service.getDemand` to a `ResponseList` that is simply not going to happen.